# password_verify php

Tags: php, mysqli

Захешировал пароль, записал в БД

```
$hpassword = password_hash($_POST['regpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);    
$insert = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO users (login,password,admin) VALUES ('$_POST[reglogin]','$hpassword','$_POST[regadmin]')");
```

Ввел пароль 1234, после хеширования получилось: $2y$10$Vq1B7/IWiiQQtZYOzbGaBOERJs7BsItru4oSApOtmeqP6ytgsQH7m

Делаю проверку:

```php
function login($link,$login,$password) {
$loginResult = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND admin='1'");

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loginResult)) {
                    $bpass = $row['password'];  
                }
                if (password_verify($password, $bpass)) {
                    $checking = true;
                    echo 'true';
                } else {
                    echo 'false';
                }
}
```

Ввожу пароль 1234,но выбивает результат проверки false

В БД у колонки с паролем тип данных стоит VARCHAR(255)

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том, что вы использовали апострофы вместо кавычек. И установился пароль $hpassword. Не значение переменной, а именно так как написано.

Comment: Это одинарная кавычка у меня. В базе все нормально, значение переменной находится

Comment: В отличие от синтаксиса двойных кавычек и heredoc, переменные и управляющие последовательности для специальных символов, заключенных в одинарные кавычки, не обрабатываются.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В отличие от синтаксиса двойных кавычек и heredoc, переменные и управляющие последовательности для специальных символов, заключенных в одинарные кавычки, не обрабатываются.

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего ошибка в этой строчке кода, а именно в том , что ты не проверяешь пароль в запросе после WHERE , как у тебя называется поле с паролем в бд если password, то пробуй так:

```
$loginResult = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password ='$hpassword'");
```

Comment: И так же проверяй поле admin='1'

Comment: Если сделаю проверку пароля, то он будет сравнивать введеный пароль с хешированным. Проверка выполняется функцией password_verify